# Exercise 2.3 in Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups (and proof verification)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, representation-theory

I am currently struggling with the following exercise from Serre's Book on linear representations of finite groups:

Let $p:G \to Gl(V)$ be a linear representation with character $\chi$ and let $V'$ be the dual of $V$, i.e., the space of linear forms on $V$. For $x \in V$, $x' \in V'$ let $\langle x,x' \rangle$ denote the value of the linear form $x'$ at $x$. Show that there exists a unique linear representation $p': G \to Gl(V')$, such that:
$$
\langle p_s x, p_s' x' \rangle = \langle x,x' \rangle \quad \text{for }s \in G, x \in V, x' \in V'
$$

So far I was able to show the uniqueness of such a linear representation as follows:

Suppose that there exist two linear representations $p',q' : G \to Gl(V)$ with said attribute. Let $s \in G$ and $(b_i)_{i \in I}$ be a basis of V and $(b_i')_{i \in I}$ be the dual basis.

Then it holds that for $i,j \in I$:
$$
\langle p_s b_j, p_s' b_i' \rangle = \langle b_j, b_i' \rangle = \langle p_s b_j, q_s' b_i' \rangle
$$
Furthermore $\langle b_j, b_i' \rangle = 1 $ if $i = j$ and $\langle b_j, b_i' \rangle = 0 $ else.

As such since $i,j \in I$ were chosen arbitrarly and the equality holds for all of them $p_s' = q_s'$(the equality from above can also be written as:)
$$
\langle p_s b_j, p_s' b_i' \rangle = \langle p_s b_j, q_s' b_i' \rangle \iff (p_s' b_i') (p_s b_j) = (q_s' b_i ')(p_s b_j)
$$
Since $s \in G$ was also chosen arbitrarly the equality of $p'$ and $q'$ is shown.

Now to the existence of such a linear representations:
Since the dual of $V$ is involved I tried constructing some basis involving the dual basis as above however I was not able to make it work. I tried constructing a map $p_s'$ with the scalars of the images of the basis when applying $p_s$ like say we have a basis as above and let
$$
p_s b_j = \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i b_i
$$
Let
$$
p_s' b_j' = \frac{1}{\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i^2} \cdot \sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i b_i'
$$
(Where the $\lambda_i$ are the same as in the images of the $b_j$ under $p_s$).

However this does not work when looking at the case where $i \neq j$ in $\langle p_s b_i, p_s' b_j' \rangle = \langle b_i,b_j' \rangle$.

As such I am kind of stuck, I also tried using Eigenvectors however that didn't seem to work either. Any tips or a check of my proof above is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is called the adjoint representation. If you want to see it in terms of matrices you can represent functionals as row vectors and then the action of $g\in G$ on $[a_1,\dots ,a_n]$ is given by $[a_1,\dots a_n] p_{g^{-1}}$ in your notation. More abstractly, this takes the functional $f: V\to \mathbb{C}$ to $f\circ p_{g^{-1}}$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. However I think I have a deeper lying problem with a matrix that's supposed to be multiplied from the right. I know that matrices can be multiplied from the right and all, however in the exercise from the book the equality states $⟨ p_s x,p′_s x′ ⟩= ⟨ x,x′ ⟩$ and not $⟨p_s x,x′ p_s'⟩=⟨x,x′⟩$. So how is it "allowed" to multiply the transformation matrix from the right? Is this due to the fact, that every linear transformation can be represented by a matrix and as such there has to a matrix which can be multiplied from the left achieving the same?

Comment: You should separate the idea of multiplication by a matrix and the idea of the application of a linear transformation. A linear transformation is a function satisfying certain abstract properties and a matrix is just a table of numbers. If you are clear about what the symbols in your formulas mean you should be able to make sense of the linear transformation $T: x' \mapsto x' \circ p_{g^{-1}}$. This $T$ is what you denote by $p'_g$. Sorry I don't have time to write a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion about "right" (in the comments) is a common one.

Let $\rho: G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be the given representation. We define $\rho': G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V')$ as follows. (Following the comment of Danny Ofek.)

1. For each $g \in G$ we need an element $\rho'_g \in \mathrm{GL}(V')$, and these elements need to satisfy $\rho'_{g_1g_2} = \rho'_{g_1}\rho'_{g_2}$.
2. Since $\rho'_g$ is an automorphism of $V'$, what we really must specify is an element $\rho'_g(x') \in V'$ for each $x'\in V'$ (and each $g \in G$, still). And, this element must also satisfy the properties of being a linear functional.
3. A linear functional takes inputs some $x \in V$. So, finally what we *really* need to do is define $\rho'_g(x')(x)$ for each $g \in G$, and $x' \in V'$ and $x \in X$.

Once you reach this final realization, you have enough to work with. You define

$$
\rho'_g(x')(x) = x'(\rho_{g^{-1}}(x)).
$$

Note that what this is in words is: $\rho'_g$ on a functional $x'$ composes $x'$ with $\rho_{g^{-1}}$ ($x'$ coming second). This what the comments mention. In terms of composition we have $\rho_{g'}x' = x' \circ \rho_{g^{-1}}$. So, in composition terms the $\rho_{g^{-1}}$ appears on the "right" and in the definition in the display it appears on left, where it should! But not fact $\rho_{g^{-1}}$ appears to the right of one thing (the $x'$) but the left of another (the $x$). To me, this is the primary confusion that arises when thinking about this $\rho'$. (Which I would call the dual representation, or contragradient. To me, the adjoint in the comments is a tensor product $\rho \otimes \rho'$. But okay.)

To understand the role of the inverse, let's check formally the property from Serre's text. We have

$$
\langle \rho_g x, \rho_g x' \rangle = (\rho_g x')(\rho_g x) = x'(\rho_{g^{-1}}(\rho_g x)) = x'(x),
$$
using that $\rho$ is a representation.

How else does the inverse arise? Remember, in steps 1.-3. you actually have to check some algebraic properties. The inverse plays a major role in step 1, in verifying that $\rho_{g_1g_2}' = \rho_{g_1}'\rho_{g_2}'$.